# "vanilla:entities" not working in Minecraft loot table

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I have this loot table in my datapack:

```
{
    "type": "minecraft:entity",
    "pools": [
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "minecraft:loot_table",
                    "name": "vanilla:entities/cow"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "weight": 1,
                    "name": "minecraft:player_head",
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "function": "set_count",
                            "count": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "function": "set_nbt",
                            "tag": "{display:{Name:'{\"text\":\"Cow.Head\",\"italic\":false}'},SkullOwner:MHF_Cow}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It's located in `datapackName/data/minecraft/loot_tables/entities/cow.json`. But when I kill a cow, it *only* drops the head, no leather or beef. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume `vanilla:entities/cow` is supposed to mention the vanilla loot table for the cow. `vanilla` is not the namepsace you are looking for. In fact, the vanilla namespace is `minecraft`. So, you will need to change it to `minecraft:entities/cow`.

But wait. Your loot table has the same namespace and filename as the vanilla loot table. This means that your loot table is overwriting the old one, making the old one inaccessible.

But I assume you actually *do* want to overwrite the old loot table with this one, but reference the old loot table inside of it. In that case, you can create a new loot table named something like `minecraft:entities/cow_old`, and put the old contents there.

For reference, the default cow loot table looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:entity",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 0.0,
                "max": 2.0,
                "type": "minecraft:uniform"
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "min": 0.0,
                "max": 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "name": "minecraft:leather"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "functions": [
            {
              "function": "minecraft:set_count",
              "count": {
                "min": 1.0,
                "max": 3.0,
                "type": "minecraft:uniform"
              }
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:furnace_smelt",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
                  "predicate": {
                    "flags": {
                      "is_on_fire": true
                    }
                  },
                  "entity": "this"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "function": "minecraft:looting_enchant",
              "count": {
                "min": 0.0,
                "max": 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "name": "minecraft:beef"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```